# Use variables from formula in R function

Tags: r, function, formula

I'd like to write a function of the type `myfunction(y,data)`, `y` being a column name of `data`. Do you have any idea on how to code it in order to be able to use the formula `myfunction(y~,data=mydata)` when calling it?

Also, how can I use someything of the form `data$y` within the function?

Comment: Why the specific need for the formula?

Comment: No specific need, I just want to pass a colname to a function

Comment: Then I would just pass a string and use it like this: `data[[string]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at `model.frame`:

```
model.frame(formula= z~y,data=data.frame(y=1:3,x=1:3,z=1:3))
  z y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

The result is a data.frame containing the variables used in formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following form of formula:

```
my_function(~y, dat)
```

and retrieve it using `as.character` inside the function. Then simply use the second element from the result of `as.character` to index the vector:

```
dat[[as.character(formula)[2]]]
```

or just skip the formula altogether and pass the string directly:

```
dat[[string]]
```

Comment: when using as.character, it gives the following result:     `[1] "~"       "Species"` Species being the colnames of y...

Comment: any idea on how to use something like data$y within the function?

Comment: @WAF You don't. The `$` function is intended primarily for interactive use. You're looking for `[[`. As in `data[[myCol]]`. Or possibly `data[,myCol]`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to pass a single column name as an unquoted string, then use this:

```
myfunction <- function(y, data)
{
    colname <- as.character(substitute(y))

    data[, colname]
}
```

Example:

```
myfunction(mpg, mtcars)
```

Note that selecting the column is done with square brackets, not with a dollar sign. That is because `$` does not evaluates the argument, and would look fora a column named `"colname"`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `y~` is not valid formula syntax but `y~.` is ok.  Using that:

1) Try this:

```
myfunction <- function(y, data) {
   if (inherits(y, "formula")) y <- all.vars(y)[1]
   data[[y]]
}
```

2) or this more extensible version using S3 dispatch:

```
# generic
myfunction <- function(y, data) UseMethod("myfunction")

# formula method
myfunction.formula <- function(y, data) {
    y <- all.vars(y)[1]
    NextMethod()
}

# default method
myfunction.default <- function(y, data) data[[y]]
```

Test it out (either solution should give the same result):

```
> myfunction(demand ~ ., BOD)
[1]  8.3 10.3 19.0 16.0 15.6 19.8
> myfunction("demand", BOD)
[1]  8.3 10.3 19.0 16.0 15.6 19.8
```

This also works:

```
> myfunction(~ demand, BOD)
[1]  8.3 10.3 19.0 16.0 15.6 19.8
```